# Restore opened vim files after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Is there is any plugin that saves all files opened in vim and opens them after reboot? For example it can be a left side panel with opened files and after you quit it saves the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vim` supports sessions. This allows you to save

```
:mksession session.vim
```

and restore

```
$ vim -S session.vim
```

sessions. See

```
:help Session
```

for the online documentation.